# Promise.all versus foreach Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await, promise

I have an Angular calculator application that calculates some results (`CalculatorResult`) grouped in sheets (like [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) ones). Say we have some six sheets.

I have a method, `calculateSheet`, that takes some properties, the sheet name, and returns some `CalculatorResult[]`:

```
async calculateSheet(
       propertyValues: PropertyValue[],
       sheetTypeName: string): Promise<CalculatorResult[]>
```

The method `calculateSheets` that calculates all six sheets,
should calculate each of the six sheets, and then aggregate all resulting arrays of the result in a single array (six arrays of CalculatorResult should become one).

So, I tried two methods to aggregate it, below:

```
// define all promises to be calculated
const promises: (() => Promise<CalculatorResult[]>)[] = [this.selectedSheetTypeName, ...(sheets.value as Sheet[]).map((sheet: Sheet) => sheet.type.name)
  .filter((sheetTypeName: string) => sheetTypeName != this.selectedSheetTypeName)]
  .map((sheetTypeName: string) => this.calculateSheet.bind(this, propertyValues, sheetTypeName));

// now, await all results, and build a common array from 6 arrays(one per sheet) of results
let results: CalculatorResult[] = [];

// WHERE IS THE DIFFERENCE OF

// THIS ONE
const myValues = await Promise.all(promises);
console.log("All 6 sheets promises here bellow:");
console.log(myValues);


// VERSUS THIS ONE
for (const promise of promises) {
  let sheetResults = await promise();
  console.log("Sheet results:")
  console.log(sheetResults)
  results.push(...sheetResults);
  console.log("All results:")
  console.log(results)
}
```

In the first case (`myValues`), why do we have six functions as the result, instead of the CalculatorResults array?

[image]

Comment: `Promise.all` queues all its promises and finally resolves when *all* its promises resolve. The loop waits for each promise to complete one by one.

Comment: the question is why in first case I have functions as result, not objects

Comment: Because you're mapping to an array of functions? `map((sheetTypeName: string) => this.calculateSheet.bind(this, propertyValues, sheetTypeName));` In the loop you're **calling** those functions.

Comment: @catgirlkelly is there a way to obtain in the first case the result of the functions?

Comment: I really don't understand why you're mapping to an array of functions that return promises. Call those functions directly and you've got your desired array of promises.

Comment: @catgirlkelly in the example bellow, I have similar call, and I don't have functions as result, but objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @serge that's because you call each function in your second example, `await promise()`.

Comment: Try this: `const myValues = await Promise.all(p => p());`

Comment: @TKoL that does not compile

Comment: sorry, wrote that wrong, `const myValues = await Promise.all(promises.map(p => p()));` I'm pretty sure that's what i meant ;)

Comment: @TKoL now is better, thanks... is strange here, I obtain the results directly... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: you mean you get the direct results of the promises into the `myValues` array right? That's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: In the screenshot it should be *"[below](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/below#Preposition)"*, not *"bellow"*. Perhaps add a verb as well.

Comment: @PeterMortensen the screenshot is sync with the code, so is bellow in both OK

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

As rule of thumb:

- If you want to execute everything in parallel and have a result as fast as you can, use `Promise.all`
- If you want to do the same as above, but have all promise results if one fails, use: [allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) or similar
- If you want to execute every promise sequentially, use `for Promise`

---

First of all, in your example the `promises` array is actually an array of functions, which you never execute, so that's why `Promise.all` returns all fns. Fix:

```
const promises = ….map((sheetTypeName: string) => this.calculateSheet(propertyValues, sheetTypeName));
```

---

`Promise.all`

**If all the promises succeed**:

- Will wait until all promises finish, and will return an array of results

**If any promise is rejected**:

- No matter when the promise is rejected nor if two or more are rejected, it will return a rejected promise containing the error of the first promise that rejected. It will happen as soon as the first error is thrown.
- You never know which promise was the one that failed. The error should contain some extra info if you want to know what promise generated it.
- If two or more promises failed, you will never know. How is the state of the other promises is unknown, since you only get the first error that happened. Other promises might not finish when the promise is rejected.
- If you want to wait for every promise is resolved/rejected, you may use [allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) or something similar.

`for promises`

The main difference is that will execute each function *sequentially*. It will wait to execute & finish the first one, to then execute the second one, and so on.

Also, you control the flow, so if the first one fails, you can choose to continue or not, or what to do.

BTW, I would never use bind to implement this, would execute every method/function directly in the `for`

Comment: you say for Promise.all, "will return an array of results", but in my case it returns array of functions, not results

Comment: Read the second paragraph where I show you how to fix your code